# Boolean flag in fact table

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

Imagine we have received the results of a health survey on daily consumption habits of 3 different items, like the following:

| Id | Date | Age | Country | CigarettesPerDay | CoffeesPerDay | BeersPerDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-31 | 35 | US | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-12-31 | 22 | US | 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-12-31 | 53 | US | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| 11276 | 2021-12-31 | 44 | France | 3 | 4 | 0 |

I want to model this in a star schema model. In the fact table, I create foreign key relationships  to date and item dimensions as well as a demographics dimension with country and age. I then sum up the number of respondents pr. demograhic group. If the number of respondents is above 100, I mark the group as being representative of the population. Finally I calculate the total and average consumption for each group.

| DateId | ItemId | DemographicId | NumberOfRespondents | IsRepresentative | TotalConsumption | AverageConsumption |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20211231 | 1 | 1 | 70 | No | 280 | 4 |
| 20211231 | 1 | 2 | 150 | Yes | 750 | 5 |
| 20211231 | 1 | 3 | 220 | Yes | 660 | 3 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| 20211231 | 3 | 1000 | 1 | No | 0 | 0 |

For instance, there was 70 respondents from demographic 1 (e.g. country = US, age = 18). They have on average consumed 4 of item 1 (e.g. cigarettes).

Generally we should strive to hold only facts and foreign keys in the fact table. However I personally don't think that a seperate dimension for the boolean flag provides any value. Can this flag be considered a generate dimension, or is it considered bad design to have it in the fact table?

Comment: Things that 1) can be calculated (`case when NumberOfRespondents > 100 then 'Yes' else 'No' end`) and 2) can change over time are not "facts" and should not be stored.

Comment: Hi mustaccio. That is true for transaction databases. But one of the purposes of an analytical data warehouse is to increase query speed for end users. Queries will be faster if calculation are performed in the ETL process.

Comment: It's often counterproductive to engage in premature optimization.

Comment: Good point! However, in this case I know the end user will want this information, and the flag will make it easier for them, as they don't need to calculate it by themselves.

Comment: Have you considered views for presentation?

Comment: @mustaccio sorry I didn't come back to you and thank you very much for your help! I have considered views, but I would prefer that the user can make fast queries, so a table will be better. Therefore I decided to put the flag in a dimension table after all.

Comment: It sounds like you believe that a view is somehow always slower to query than its underlying table; have you done any tests to confirm that assumption?

Comment: I haven't done tests per say, but it is my experience that views can often become slow to query. Persistent tables will be superior to views, since there is no need for expensive calculations when querying the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really an answer, but in lack of good ideas, I decided to put the flag in a dimension table after all.